# Architecture Best Practice (MVC): Repository Returns Object & Object Member Accessed Directly or Repository Returns Object Member

Tags: php, object-oriented-design, encapsulation, coupling, single-responsibility

Architecturally speaking, which is the preferable approach (and why)?

```
$validation_date = $users_repository->getUser($user_id)->validation_date;
```

- Seems to violate Law of Demeter by accessing member of object returned by method call
- Seems to violate Encapsulation by accessing object member directly

`$validation_date = $users_repository->getUserValidationDate($user_id);`

- Seems to violate Single Responsibility Principle as $users_repository no longer just returns User objects

Comment: I would rather ask myself if a `validation_date` really is a part of a user?  to me, that's a violation of SRP. validation_date, password, activation code etc belongs rather to an `Account` used to login an `User`. Else the  `User` entity got two reasons to change: Changed account details and changed user details

Comment: @jgauffin: I guess coderabbi uses "*user*" as a synonym for "*account*", in the sense that it stores the data about the "*user account*" ;)

Comment: What would be the point of returning objects if you weren't going to access their members?!

Comment: I dont mean to sound like a dick.. but this has to be the first time I've seen a PHP developer actually concerned about these principles.. I salute you though :)

Comment: How about $validation_date = $users_repository->getUser($user_id)->getUserValidationDate();

Comment: @jgauffun - arnaud is correct - in this case user/account are essentially synonymous.

Comment: @AakashM - Fair question on the surface, though ideally if I wanted to get at an object's members, I would utilize dependency injection and pass in the object as a parameter.  The question only exists in this case because that isn't possible.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead - you've obviously been hanging around the wrong PHP programmers... :)  Seriously, though, these concerns aren't all that uncommon - PHP has matured significantly with 5.3 & 5.4 and we're seeing a lot more architectural thought perhaps once reserved for enterprise applications (and therefore other languages) going into PHP applications.

Comment: @onlineapplab.com - That would certainly solve the issue of Encapsulation.  The Law of Demeter & the Single Responsibility Principle would still be in tension between the approaches, however.

Comment: @coderabbi
$user_repository would return only User objects so Single Responsibility Principle would not be violated.

Comment: ^ meanwhile your competitor has not wasted time agonizing over architectural principles and actually shipped a product - woopsie

Comment: @MattDavey - A product which is untestable, unflexible, unmaintainable and developer hostile.  I'll take the 'architectural principles' agony over that sort of agony any day...

Comment: @coderabbi I wasn't gibing at your question at all :) - I was just trying to point out that your code sample isn't exactly a piece of coding horror. It's an exaggeration to call it untestable, unflexible, unmaintainable and developer hostile. Strict adherence to principles needs to be evaluated against the cost. If that line of code is causing you serious problems then by all means consider a refactor, but it looks like you only have a vague notion that it _"seems to violate Single Responsibility Principle"_, does that alone justify spending time refactoring towards some imagined ideal?

Comment: I guess my real point is this... I've discovered to my cost that perfectionism can turn around and bite you in the rear end, so my honest advice based on painful personal experience is not to let your perfectionism take over, sometimes you've just got to say "it's not perfect but it works and that's OK" :)

Comment: @MattDavey - I agree with you 100% not to let a question of this nature block progress on a project.  However, not to note it and offer it up to your peers for discussion typically means that the question will remain for the next project.  And even that wouldn't be so bad if it was only one question, but each question is just... one question.  Lots of those in a pile?  Code which is... untestable, unflexible, unmaintainable and developer hostile.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The  technically 'correct' way to deal with this problem is to pass the correct User object into the method (or class) which is going to require "validation_date". Where possible, Dependency Injecting the exact object required should always be favoured over injecting Repositories, ServiceLocators and factories. The smallest required component should be passed in to the method that requires it. The code in the question doesn't really have a dependency on the repository but on the user.

It's not a Law of Demeter violation because, as the question suggests, the code needs access to the validation date. It's a Law of Demeter violation because the repository is only used as a gateway to other objects.

See http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-digging-into-collaborators/ for a detailed explanation of the problem and the best way to fix it.

Comment: I find it interesting that this answer was down-voted. I take dependency injection as pretty much a given (though admittedly in this partially contrived exampleI was assuming injection of the user repository rather than the user object itself). That approach may not be possible here, as the code in question exists at the 'outermost' level, the controller - my IoC container can inject the repository but not a specific object.  The basis of the question then is how to get at the property once the injected repository is used to retrieve the user object.  My upvote brings you to zero - thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why it was downvoted either, perhaps because it wasn't detailed enough. Anyway, I believe the issue, then, is a workaround for a limitation of your IoC container rather than a purely OO conceptual one. From a pure OOP perspective it's always best to inject the smallest, simplest level needed.  In this instance, you're getting $user_id from somewhere. Use a User object instead of a scalar $user_id and this is a non-issue. It may present practical problems due to higher level architectural decisions but from a OO purist perspective this is the ideal methodology.

Comment: @TomB I didn't downvote this answer, but on the surface it sounds odd because it seems to be saying that developers have to choose between Dependency Injection and Repositories as if they are mutually exclusive. Which is clearly not the case, and probably not what you are saying.

Comment: @Tom B - And if the $user_id comes from $_GET['user_id']?   :)

Comment: I believe this highlights a SoC issue that is prevalant in most PHP frameworks that don't correctly implement MVC. In MVC proper, controllers don't contain domain logic. Ideally the program flow would be: Controller gets $id, pulls the user from the repo then passes it into a model method for validation. This way the controller never has an knowledge of domain logic and the model is agnostic about where its domain entity comes from -it shouldn't have to come from the repository see http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2008/12/the-m-in-mvc-why-models-are-misunderstood-and-unappreciated/ for more info

Comment: @Eric King thanks. I've updated the answer to be clearer.

Comment: @TomB - It isn't really a question of domain logic here - my choice of $validation_date for the example is incidental.  Assume that the user merely wants to retrieve an arbitrary piece of user data (birthday if it's easier) via an AJAX call.  The flow is then going to be as you described it, but only to a point: controller gets $id, pulls the user from the repo... then what? Pass it to a model method simply to extract a date?  Really?!  So the question is as asked - ideally, should the controller access the property directly, or should a repository method handle that?

Comment: That's display logic. In this example, the controller never needs access to the birthday/validation date. The controller would set the model's state: "This is the user that is being dealt with" and the View would request the user from the model. The fact that the view only needs an arbitrary piece of information from the user is no concern of the controller's or model's. This way, the controller and model are reusable with any number of views incidental of what data is being displayed-- The whole point of separating the components in the first place.

Comment: I should clarify this as as well: the only reason that the controller has access to the repository in this scenario is because you have to convert user_id to a user object somewhere. In a desktop application this would all be handled in the model because it's able to be persistent. On the web persistence isn't possible so some concessions must be made.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, picking what's the most intuitive is the best rule of thumb.

Many people actually don't even agree with the laws/rules/principles you stated. I.e. the functional programming is clearly going away from OO and tries to separate data from processing, I think nobody cares about LoD for such trivial stuff, and the Single Responsibility stuff, although nice, is sometimes hard to achieve in the real world.

That being said, IMHO and this particular example, I find the first alternative the most direct and intuitive.